# since Postgres 13 can't connect from heroku-app to hobby-dev db without ssl

Tags: postgresql, heroku, connection

I have a node application connecting to postgres.
The version I setup on Heroku months ago, this has as addon Heroku Postgres 12, connects without problem with the provided DATABASE_URL.

When I now create a new Heroku app with the exact same git repository, add a Postgres addon (but now it's version 13) I have connection error:

```
Error during migration run:
{ error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "34.252.159.221", user "xx", database "xx", SSL off
```

(heroku credentials left out here)

I have tried solutions like adding `sslmode=required` to the url, but then I get `Error: self signed certificate`

What should I do to connect to my Postgres 13 database?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the corresponding entry in the PostgreSQL log?

Answer (score 0):

found it. It's in the docs.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js
I guess that this is needed was added in the last 9 months, as I didn't have to do this in previous projects

In connection config object:

```
  ssl: config.ENV === 'production' && {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
```

Comment: I don't recall this as being new.  I think you just have your two databases configured differently.